# Real time communication between android app and dispatch panel

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, parsing, socket.io

I'm going to drive a solution like Ola and Uber Taxi app booking system, so here I want to establish real time communication among Dispatch panel, customer app, and driver app. But I don't know that how it will take place. For dispatch panel I want to use **Parse** with **PHP**, I can use some other technology like **nodejs** if you will suggest me.

**Use-case** for real time communication-

1- When customer searches a Cab and going to book then this request should be show to the nearest 3-drivers (driver app) after that any one of them driver accepts this request customer will notify that this particular driver accepted and coming for pickup. And this same flow of Requests/Responses will monitor by the Dispatch panel too.

I look into following link but these are unable to fulfill my requirement..
[Real-Time communication between PHP and Flex application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224153/real-time-communication-between-php-and-flex-application)

[Real-time communication between app and webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985577/real-time-communication-between-app-and-webpage)

So please guide me for the same

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scale of your application, there several things you can try to keep drivers constantly informed of new bookings, but I think that polling is the way to go in order to scale:

Each driver app will poll the server every TBD time (say, once a minute), to see if it has new bookings, and if it does, it will display it to the driver.

The dispatch application, assuming it has small number of instances, under 20 or so, and is installed on stationary computers (i.e. desktop app), can use constant connection to the dispatch server, using a TCP pipeline, in order to receive faster notifications about bookings.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Itai Bar-Haim for your valuable views. I suppose to implement like live streaming of all Cabs and these status in android App as well as Dispatch panel

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems where you have to take care of.

First is the technique you are using for the communication and the second one, which is more important, is, how does your solution scales.

If you use a ajax solution and you get more and more users, you will get trouble on the server side and it is not an easy job to scale it.

In my opinion the best solution is to use a NoSQL provider like cloudant and on the client side something like pouchDB.

I use this combination in a cordova app with about 1000 users / 500k entries and it works very well.

Comment: Thanks @joerg, So according to you one thing is going to fixed that I should use NoSQL provider okay fine, Now what about Real Time Communication between app and dispatch panel. Please give your views for the same because this is also a very important part of such kind of systems.

Comment: PouchDB is a javascript solution, so you can use it also in the browser.